# help using django's ORM for UNION query

Tags: django, orm

i am making a history page for a website. The structure of my classes is something like this:

[image]

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class History(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Parent(Person):
    #some attributes that are not relevant

class Son(Person)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    #other attributes that are not relevant
```

its quite simple... i have a **Parent** that has multiple **Sons** both can do **actions** on the website and they are all saved in the History table that has a reference to the Person that executed the action. The history table is something like:

```
date       | action        | person_id 
----------------------------------------
16-12-2010 | saved profile | 1
16-12-2010 | new child     | 2
```

for a Parent i need to display all his actions and the action of his sons
Using sql it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM History where person_id=1 
UNION 
SELECT h.* FROM History h JOIN Son s ON s.person_ptr_id=h.person_id WHERE s.parent_id=1
```

but i have no idea how to do that using django's ORM. Myabe using two querys? a loop? 
Do you have any ideas? i'd really appreciate some help.. thanks in advance

BTW: i'm using django 1.1

**EDIT:** i added the attributes in the classes. These are just examples, my tables have more attributes, but this is how django translate the relations into tables

Comment: Can you post the source code of the models? The foreign key relations would suffice.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong: Are you modeling `Person` as an abstract class in Django? Also, are `Parent` and `Son` being modeled as separate classes? This would mean different tables. Does it make sense to model them using one class, with a foreign key pointing to the same class?

Comment: well this is just an exemple of the real tables that i'm using, where parent and sons have different attributes and also different relations to other tables.. so it's easier for me to separate them in different tables

Comment: OK. In that case you should first come out with suitable _Django_ model classes I think. It would be easier to work out a query after that.

Comment: o_o .. but.. the django models are not different than the diagram, i mean, the heritance and the 1xN relations are there on my django models, and the query I need is the one I posted, but i dont know how to create the queryset.. it must be something like History.objects.filter(Q(person__id=1)|Q("history for all sons of Parent with id=1"))

Comment: Ah. It would be more useful if you could post the code of the models. I am still not sure if your `Person` class is abstract (in which `History` cannot have a FK to it) or not (in which case there are three tables namely Person, Parent and Son)

Comment: done!.. and i forgot.. the person is not abstract and yes there are four tables: History, Person, Parent and Son =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the sql:

```
p = Parent.objects.get(id=1)
history_qs = History.objects.all()
history_qs = history_qs.filter(Q(person=p)|Q(person__in=Son.objects.filter(parent=p)))
```

The union is not necesary.